# Estilos con react

Tags: reactjs

Necesito saber como puedo hacer para detectar un `hover` en un elemento y alterar otro, ejemplo:

```
saludo: {
        display: 'iinline',
        marginTop: '1.5rem',
        fontWeight: 600
    },
    text: {
        marginTop: '-1.3rem',
        border: 'none',
        outline: 'none',
        position: 'relative',
        zIndex: 50,
        height: 'auto',
        minHeight: '3rem',
        '&:hover' > saludo:{ //esto obviamente no funciona, pero estoy buscando algo asi 
            
        }
    }
```

Estoy usando un simple `createStyles` en react y necesito que al hacer `hover` en un elemento se altere otro pero no se como hacerlo.

Answer (score 1):

Pues no seria tanto el utilizar `CSS`, seria mejor utilizar dos funciones como el de `onMouseEnter`, que se activa cuando el mouse entra en el elemento y `onMouseLeave`, que se activa cuando el mouse sale del elemento, Utilizando ambas acciones se consigue el `hover` que deseas.

**Ejemplo:**

```
export default function App() {
  var [state,setState]=useState({
    width:"100px",
    height:"100px",
    border:"1px solid blue",
    background:"blue"
  });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div 
        className="padre" 
        style={padre}
        onMouseEnter={() => setState({...state,background:"red"})}
        onMouseLeave={() => setState({...state,background:"blue"})}
      >
        <div className="hijo" style={state}>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
const padre={
  display:"flex",
  justifyContent:"center",
  alignItems:"center",
  width:"300px",
  height:"300px",
  border:"1px solid red"
}
```

En este ejemplo solo cambio el `background` del `div.hijo`, pero puedes hacer todo lo que te imagines.

Te dejo el [ejemplo funcional](https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-framework-n0z7y?file=/src/App.js) para que puedas ver en acción.

Comment: gracias, ya lo habia echo con funciones, solo buscaba una alternativa a eso para hacerlo mas sencillo